# Is tile primer suitable for plastering in bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, primer

I've plasterboarded using moisture resistant board and plan to title round the bath using [Tile Adhesive Primer](http://www.screwfix.com/p/mapei-tile-adhesive-primer-1kg/87305) first. I was wondering whether this primer is also suitable for plastering the opposite side of the bathroom rather than using PVA?

Comment: Good luck with applying tile to MR drywall, even with tile primer. I would have encouraged you to use hardy-backer or concrete board as a backer for grouted tile instead of blue/green board.

Comment: What are you going to "plaster" the other walls with?

Comment: was thinking thistle multi-finish

Comment: I see this is a European product I am not real familiar with.  I looked it up on the internet and it looks like a hard plaster finish.  If you put this on drywall, you are going to need a good sealer on the rock and perhaps a bonding layer.